# Would like to test for an expected error when using a purposefully bad JSON payload

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockmvc

I am using Junit and MockMVC for some integration tests...one of our tests worked as expected until we just upgraded to Spring Boot 2.2.5.

```
    mockMvc.perform(
            post("/experiments")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(requestPayload)) // requestPayload is a purposefully invalid JSON string with a missing bracket
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
```

It can't finish the test because the updated Spring version throws an error before it finishes the request due to the bad JSON (per the error below). Is there a way to get mockMVC to expect the bad JSON in my test?

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: JSON conversion problem: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 232] (through reference chain: com.allstate.d3.sh.commons.rest.ExperimentDetail["buckets"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: JSON conversion problem: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('{' (code 123)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 232] (through reference chain: com.allstate.d3.sh.commons.rest.ExperimentDetail["buckets"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the exception is not thrown in `MockMvc` but in your application. You could register a `RestControllerAdvice` to handle it and produce the bad request response that you are expecting:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ErrorController {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageConversionException.class)
    public String handleBadRequest(Exception e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mathias...I actually worked around it by writing a custom rule with the @Rule annotation to expect the 500 error, but I think this would work as well.